# Conditionally Merging two rows in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a access query which return data in the form of

Study_ID    TextData    sOption
290 Reason-Relaxing NO
290 Reason-Relaxing NO
290 Reason-Addiction    NO
290 Reason-Addiction    NO
290 Reason-Habit    YES
290 Reason-Habit    NO
290 Reason-Stress   YES
290 Reason-Stress   NO
290 Reason-Other    NO
290 Reason-Other    NO

291 Reason-Relaxing YES
291 Reason-Relaxing NO
291 Reason-Addiction    NO
291 Reason-Addiction    NO
291 Reason-Habit    NO
291 Reason-Habit    NO
291 Reason-Stress   NO
291 Reason-Stress   YES
291 Reason-Other    NO
291 Reason-Other    NO

NO what i want is to have this data on the basis of study id, if for any study id text data i.e reson are same and soption is atleast  true for once it should show true if false then no

i.e

Study_ID    TextData    sOption
290 Reason-Relaxing NO
290 Reason-Addiction    NO
290 Reason-Habit    YES
290 Reason-Stress   YES
290 Reason-Other    NO

291 Reason-Relaxing YES
291 Reason-Addiction    NO
291 Reason-Habit    NO
291 Reason-Stress   YES
291 Reason-Other    NO

Notice if both option for a reason was 'no' then option is retained as 'no' else option is set 'yes' and the rows are combined as a single row

How can i achieve this functionality in access

Comment: Could you post the query that generates the above results?

Comment: SELECT Study_ID, 'Reason-'& Text_data AS TextData, Switch  (
Value_Data=cstr(Reason_Id ), 'YES',
Value_Data<>cstr(Reason_Id) , 'NO'

) AS sOption
FROM PatientRelatesSmokingContinueReasons, (select Text_data , Value_Data
from mstMasterLookup where
Table = 'Smoking_Continue_Reason' )  AS tblReason
order by Study_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT StudyID, TextData, Max(SOption) as SOption2
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY StudyID, TextData
ORDER BY StudyID, TextData
```

When you group by, use "Max(SOption) as SOption2". Since Y is greater than N, it will return 'Yes' for any record that has both 'Yes' and 'No'.